# Excel formula to capture cell value within certain distance

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of about 100 x 100 cells with all numerical values. I would like to calculate the sum of a range only if cells within this range have a distance smaller than a specific value.

i.e.

```
SQRT((ROW(specific cell)-ROW(any cell within the range))^2 + (COLUMN(specific cell) - COLUMN(any cell within the range))^2) < 5
```

How should I write this formula?

All I can think of is to use the `sumif` function but I'm stuck on writing the condition 
`=SUMIF(B4:AN42,"condition???")`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `=SUMIF(B4:AN42,"<5")`

[More](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

Comment: doesn't work because it shows the sum of cells with value < 5 not the sum of cell value with distance smaller than 5 from a target cell

Comment: So, You can use **offset** [More](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that OFFSET function may be just right solution for you (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). Quoting above article:

"OFFSET doesn't actually move any cells or change the selection; it just returns a reference. OFFSET can be used with any function expecting a reference argument. For example, the formula `SUM(OFFSET(C2,1,2,3,1))` calculates the total value of a 3-row by 1-column range that is 1 row below and 2 columns to the right of cell C2."